# Create a quick start wordpress installation

Tags: php, themes, mysql, installation

How to create an installation package that when installing, already install the theme that I created, plugins and demo content? I do not find any documentation on the subject. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This seems like a very broad topic to get a direct answer to. There are a few many Git repositories on the subject if you look on Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that installs the wordpress just the way you like it. Roughly could be like this:

1. Install Wordpress.
2. Install the themes, plugins and demo content you want.
3. zip the files
4. Export database into a file

The script needs to unpackage and copy the files into a folder. Then replace the information on the sql script like base url, site name etc.

You could also make apache configs and other settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Vagrant Varying Vagrants](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) paired with [VV](https://github.com/bradp/vv).

You can actually create blueprints and spin up local installs of wordpress in a snap.

It's what I use for local development.